# Может не стоит выделять серым цветом ответы с отрицательным рейтингом?

Tags: обсуждение

Просто невозможно читать такие ответы - глаза сломаешь)))

Получается, что если ответ уже с отрицательным рейтингом, то его как бы нельзя читать и выразить свою точку зрения...

Comment: Это вы знаете, что отрицательный рейтинг ставит содержимое сообщения под сомнение. А этот хак объясняет сей факт всем остальным. И эффект, помнится, мгновенно устраняется наведением мыши, нет?

Comment: Проверил, устраняется. Но не в мобильной версии.

Comment: @D-side зато в мобильном клиенте вообще не затеняется.

Comment: Не знал, что устраняется при наведении ))) Если бы не задал вопрос, то и не узнал бы)))))))

Answer (score 6):

Технически:

- В десктопной версии сайта «цвет» возвращается, когда вы наводите курсор на вопрос.
- В мобильном клиенте вообще нет выделения серым.
- В мобильной версии сайта цвет не возвращается. Решается просто — поставьте мобильный клиент.

По сути:

Серый цвет появляется на -3 и ниже. Как правило, это бывает неслучайно — ответ действительно плохой. Такое оформление снижает шанс, что кто-нибудь слепо скопипастит код и в результате получит проблемы.

Comment: Не знал, что устраняется при наведении ))) Если бы не задал вопрос, то и не узнал бы))))))).... Сейчас заметил, ответы занимают 2/3 сайта слева... курсор, почему у меня справа находится... рядом со скроллбаром

Comment: начиная -3 вроде как